# using bootstrap's column pull/push

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i am new to bootstrap. i have designed a structure which is fairly simple it contains two main columns of **col-lg-6** the first column contains an image and the second one contains a text now what my structure is that

col-xs-12 col-md-6             col-xs-12 col-md-6

image                                       some text

col-xs-12 col-md-6             col-xs-12 col-md-6

some text                            image

now what happens in mobile view that the left column gets the priority to come first but what i want is when the second row starts there is a text column which should come first but i want the image column(the very next column) to come first i studied bootstrap's pull/push but i can really get to use it in my scenario more over there is no such detail mentioned on the bootstrap website as well.. here is my actual code

```
 <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="padding-right: 0;">
                    <div class="arrow">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>images/community-work-4.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                    <h2>Food Drive</h2>
                    <!--                    <h3>Date: Dec 22, 2016</h3>-->
                    <!--                    <br/>-->
                    <h4>Team Carassauga Pakistan Pavilion 2016 was honoured to be a part of community food drive to support ICNA Canada and Eden Food Bank. Every year from 2007 to 2012, approximately 5% of Canadian children and 8% of Canadian adults lived in food insecure households. This means that they did not have access to a sufficient variety or quantity of food due to lack of money. Community food drives can bring positive change in providing families with food and other basic necessities for better living...</h4><br/>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>home/community_individual/3">Continue Reading</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <h2>Cultural Exchange</h2>
                    <!--                    <h3>Date: Dec 22, 2016</h3>-->
                    <!--                    <br/>-->
                    <h4>Team Carassauga Pakistan Pavilion, gained its title through the work and effort they invested in for about a year to put together the beautiful marriage of cultural exchange and wholesome hosting, opening their doors through the fantastic platform of Carassauga 2016 held at Hershey Sports Centre, to the fellow Torontonians. This was a successful attempt by the team at embracing their Pakistani identity and harmonizing it with the true Canadian values of acceptance and diversity...<br/>
                        <br/>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>home/community_individual/2">Continue Reading</a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="padding-left: 0;">
                    <div class="arrow-right">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>images/culture.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="padding-right: 0;">
                    <div class="arrow">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>images/community-work-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                    <h2>Muslim Welfare </h2>
                    <!--                    <h3>Date: Dec 22, 2016</h3>-->
                    <!--                    <br/>-->
                    <h4>Team Carassauga Pakistan Pavilion 2016 was honoured to volunteer with Muslim Welfare Center in Scarborough for the food drive. As a Canadian it is our responsibility to help out unprivileged individuals with the best of our abilities that we take for granted......</h4>
                    <br/>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>home/community_individual/1">Continue Reading</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

any sort of help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why is the code a mix of `col-md-6` and `col-md-4`? Do you want both image and text  `col-md-6`?

Comment: naa actually on the right column i dont dont need the full space so i just left two columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to think "mobile-first". That means create the desired **small layout first**. Then adjust the columns using **push/pull for the larger** layout...

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/lcNRCPKZ2s

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
            <div class="arrow-right">
                img
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
              text
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/lcNRCPKZ2s)

Comment: alright done!i will accept the answer in four minutes! but i am still confused i need to adjust my design for mobile so dont i need to add col-md-push-6 to mobile coulmns? lile col-xs-push-12??

Comment: no in this case you don't need to because the columns are full width on mobile by default.